# How to use LocalDateTime RequestParam in Spring? I get "Failed to convert String to LocalDateTime"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-time, jsr310

I use Spring Boot and included `jackson-datatype-jsr310` with Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to use a RequestParam with a Java 8 Date/Time type,

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public Page<User> get(
    @RequestParam(value = "start", required = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime start) {
//...
}
```

and test it with this URL:

```
/test?start=2016-10-8T00:00
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1477528408379,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException",
  "message": "Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.LocalDateTime]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2016-10-8T00:00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2016-10-8T00:00]",
  "path": "/test"
}
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**TL;DR** - you can capture it as a string with just `@RequestParam`, or you can have Spring additionally parse the string into a java date / time class via `@DateTimeFormat` on the parameter as well.

The `@RequestParam` is enough to grab the date you supply after the = sign. However, it comes into the method as a `String`. That is why it is throwing the cast exception.

There are a few ways to achieve this:

1. Parse the date yourself, grabbing the value as a string.

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
public Page<User> get(@RequestParam(value="start", required = false) String start){

    //Create a DateTimeFormatter with your required format:
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = 
            new DateTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);

    //Next parse the date from the @RequestParam, specifying the TO type as a TemporalQuery:
   LocalDateTime date = dateTimeFormat.parse(start, LocalDateTime::from);
    
    //Do the rest of your code...
}
```

2. Leverage Spring's ability to automatically parse and expect date formats:

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
public void processDateTime(@RequestParam("start") 
                            @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) 
                            LocalDateTime date) {
        // The rest of your code (Spring already parsed the date).
}
```

Comment: Sure, but there is one major problem - why use custom controller, if for most of those requests You could use Spring JPA Repositories? And this is the place when actually problem with this error starts ;/

Comment: You could also use this solution in the signature method: `@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime start`

Comment: @Anna please post your comment as an answer as it should be the accepted one imo

Comment: Thank-you, approach 2 works for me as sometimes i pass minuets, and other times i don't need too. this just takes care of all that :)

Answer (score 99):

You did everything correct :) . [Here](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-from-the-trenches/tree/master/datetimeformat-annotation) is an example that shows exactly what you are doing. *Just* Annotate your RequestParam with `@DateTimeFormat`. There is no need for special `GenericConversionService` or manual conversion in the controller. [This](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-parsing-date-and-time-information-from-a-request-parameter/) blog post writes about it.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/datetime/")
final class DateTimeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "datetime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processDateTime(@RequestParam("datetime") 
                                @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime dateAndTime) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

I guess you had an issue with the format. On my setup everything works well.

Comment: I went with this advice, and it worked, but then I wondered if the annotation could be applied to the entire controller method...and it turns out it can. It _cannot_ be applied to the entire controller, though: `@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface DateTimeFormat {`.

Comment: Notwithstanding my comment above, moving the annotation from a request parameter (two of them, actually: `startDate` and `endDate`) to the request method seemed to break the method's behavior for the worse.

Comment: This works well for date patterns that don't have timestamps, but if you include a timestamp in the pattern, it fails to convert the String to a Date (or other applicable type).

Comment: I was wrong, this works just fine with timestamps, but if you copy-paste the example that is in the JavaDoc for org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME, it'll fail. The example that they provide should have X instead of Z for its pattern as they included -05:00 as opposed to -0500.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works if you pass date or DateTime, but when the values are EMPTY, this is failing.

Answer (score 48):

I found workaround [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4113#issuecomment-258832899).

> Spring/Spring Boot only supports the date/date-time format in BODY parameters.

The following configuration class adds support for date/date-time in QUERY STRING (request parameters):

```
// Since Spring Framwork 5.0 & Java 8+
@Configuration
public class DateTimeFormatConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
        registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
    }
}
```

respectively:

```
// Until Spring Framwork 4.+
@Configuration
public class DateTimeFormatConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
        registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
    }
}
```

It works even if you bind multiple request parameters to some class (`@DateTimeFormat` annotation helpless in this case):

```
public class ReportRequest {
    private LocalDate from;
    private LocalDate to;

    public LocalDate getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(LocalDate from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public LocalDate getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(LocalDate to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
}

// ...

@GetMapping("/api/report")
public void getReport(ReportRequest request) {
// ...
```

Comment: how to catch convert exception here?

Comment: This is the best answer. It works even if the Date field is a nested field. It's also better because this way you just have to add this config once.

Comment: Whoa! Trawled through half the internet to get here... Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

Like I put in the comment, you could also use this solution in the signature method: `@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime start`

Answer (score 17):

#### SpringBoot 2.X.X and newer

If you use the dependency [`spring-boot-starter-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.0.0.RELEASE) version `2.0.0.RELEASE` or higher, there is no longer needed to explicitely include `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency, which is already provided with `spring-boot-starter-web` through [`spring-boot-starter-json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.0.0.RELEASE).

This was resolved as Spring Boot issue [#9297](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9297) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531307/3764965) **is still** valid and relevant:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "datetime", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void foo(
        @RequestParam("dateTime") 
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime ldt) {

    // IMPLEMENTATION
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and found my solution [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/86986-datetimeformat-for-pathvariable-not-converting?p=514620#post514620) (without using  Annotations)

> ...you must at least properly register a string to [LocalDateTime] Converter in
>   your context, so that Spring can use it to automatically do this for
>   you every time you give a String as input and expect a [LocalDateTime]. (A big
>   number of converters are already implemented by Spring and contained
>   in the core.convert.support package, but none involves a [LocalDateTime]
>   conversion)

So in your case you would do this:

```
public class StringToLocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {
    public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
        return LocalDateTime.parse(source, formatter);
    }
}
```

and then just register your bean:

```
<bean class="com.mycompany.mypackage.StringToLocalDateTimeConverter"/>
```

**With Annotations**

add it to your ConversionService:

```
@Component
public class SomeAmazingConversionService extends GenericConversionService {

    public SomeAmazingConversionService() {
        addConverter(new StringToLocalDateTimeConverter());
    }

}
```

and finally you would then @Autowire in your ConversionService:

```
@Autowired
private SomeAmazingConversionService someAmazingConversionService;
```

You can read more about conversions with spring (and formatting) on this [site](http://javabeat.net/introduction-to-spring-converters-and-formatters/). Be forewarned it has a ton of ads, but I definitely found it to be a useful site and a good intro to the topic.

Answer (score 4):

Following works well with Spring Boot 2.1.6:

**Controller**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class RequestController {

    @GetMapping
    public String test(RequestParameter param) {
        log.info("Called services with parameter: " + param);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = param.getCreated().plus(10, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
        LocalDate date = param.getCreatedDate().plus(10, ChronoUnit.YEARS);

        String result = "DATE_TIME: " + dateTime + "<br /> DATE: " + date;
        return result;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public LocalDate post(@RequestBody PostBody body) {
        log.info("Posted body: " + body);
        return body.getDate().plus(10, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
    }
}
```

**Dto classes:**

```
@Value
public class RequestParameter {
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE_TIME)
    LocalDateTime created;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE)
    LocalDate createdDate;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PostBody {
    LocalDate date;
}
```

**Test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(RequestController.class)
public class RequestControllerTest {

    @Autowired MockMvc mvc;
    @Autowired ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Test
    public void testWsCall() throws Exception {
        String pDate        = "2019-05-01";
        String pDateTime    = pDate + "T23:10:01";
        String eDateTime = "2029-05-01T23:10:01"; 

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("")
            .param("created", pDateTime)
            .param("createdDate", pDate))
          .andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andReturn();

        String payload = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(payload).contains(eDateTime);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMapper() throws Exception {
        String pDate        = "2019-05-01";
        String eDate        = "2029-05-01";
        String pDateTime    = pDate + "T23:10:01";
        String eDateTime    = eDate + "T23:10:01"; 

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("")
            .param("created", pDateTime)
            .param("createdDate", pDate)
        )
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();

        String payload = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(payload).contains(eDate).contains(eDateTime);
    }


    @Test
    public void testPost() throws Exception {
        LocalDate testDate = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JANUARY, 1);

        PostBody body = PostBody.builder().date(testDate).build();
        String request = mapper.writeValueAsString(body);

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("")
            .content(request).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        )
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();

        ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader().forType(LocalDate.class);
        LocalDate payload = reader.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
        assertThat(payload).isEqualTo(testDate.plus(10, ChronoUnit.YEARS));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers above didn't work for me, but I blundered on to one which did here:  https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/08/parsing-of-localdate-query-parameters-in-spring-boot/   The winning snippet was the ControllerAdvice annotation, which has the advantage of applying this fix across all your controllers:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class LocalDateTimeControllerAdvice
{

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder( WebDataBinder binder )
    {
        binder.registerCustomEditor( LocalDateTime.class, new PropertyEditorSupport()
        {
            @Override
            public void setAsText( String text ) throws IllegalArgumentException
            {
                LocalDateTime.parse( text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can global configure datetime format in `application properties`.
Like:

> spring.mvc.format.date=yyyy-MM-dd

> spring.mvc.format.date-time=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

> spring.mvc.format.time=HH:mm:ss

Check in  mavern: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.5.3

Answer (score 1):

You can add to config, this solution does work with optional as well as with non-optional parameters.

```java
@Bean
    public Formatter<LocalDate> localDateFormatter() {
        return new Formatter<>() {
            @Override
            public LocalDate parse(String text, Locale locale) {
                return LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
            }

            @Override
            public String print(LocalDate object, Locale locale) {
                return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.format(object);
            }
        };
    }


    @Bean
    public Formatter<LocalDateTime> localDateTimeFormatter() {
        return new Formatter<>() {
            @Override
            public LocalDateTime parse(String text, Locale locale) {
                return LocalDateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
            }

            @Override
            public String print(LocalDateTime object, Locale locale) {
                return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(object);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another general solution with parameter converter:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import ru.diasoft.micro.msamiddleoffice.ftcaa.customerprofile.config.JacksonConfig;

import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime>{

    private static final List<String> SUPPORTED_FORMATS = Arrays.asList("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "[another date time format ...]");
    private static final List<DateTimeFormatter> DATE_TIME_FORMATTERS = SUPPORTED_FORMATS
            .stream()
            .map(DateTimeFormatter::ofPattern)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(String s) {

        for (DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter : DATE_TIME_FORMATTERS) {
            try {
                return LocalDateTime.parse(s, dateTimeFormatter);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
                // deliberate empty block so that all parsers run
            }
        }

        throw new DateTimeException(String.format("unable to parse (%s) supported formats are %s",
                s, String.join(", ", SUPPORTED_FORMATS)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same error it got fixed as the date represented in spring was yyyy/mm/dd
and i was passing yyyy-mm-dd '/' was required i was sending '-' so made the changed and it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
```

then in your angular constructor :

```
private datePipe: DatePipe
```

From your frontend(Angular) convert the selected date like this :

```
      const date = this.datePipe.transform(this.searchDashboardEntryForm.get('acceptedOn').value, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Using date pipe now its turned to a clean date format like this : **yyyy-MM-dd**

From yout backend(java) make the request param like this :

```
            @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate date
```

Answer (score 0):

For global configuration :

```
public class LocalDateTimePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        setValue(LocalDateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
    }

}
```

And then

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class InitBinderHandler {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) { 
        binder.registerCustomEditor(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimePropertyEditor());
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `LocalDateTimePropertyEditor` supposed to be `OffsetDateTimePropertyEditor`, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a related context

I am using WebRequestDataBinder to map the request params to a model dynamically.

```
Object domainObject = ModelManager.getEntity(entityName).newInstance();
WebRequestDataBinder binder = new WebRequestDataBinder(domainObject);
binder.bind(request);
```

This piece of code is working for primitives but did not work for LocalDateTime type attributes

To fix the problem, before calling binder.bind, I registered a custom editor before calling bind()

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDateTime.class, new PropertyEditorSupport()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException
                    {
                        setValue(LocalDateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getAsText() {
                        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format((LocalDateTime) getValue());
                    }

                }
            );
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior occured to me whilst working with an **Swagger OpenAPI Endpoint** ...

The OpenAPI definition looked alike:

```
paths:
  /endpoint:
    get:
      summary: short summary
      operationId: endpointFunction
      parameters:
        - name: timestamp
          in: query
          description: 'Given timestamp'
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
            format: date-time
            example: "2023-01-05T13:11:40.020747+01:00"
      responses:
        200:
          description: 'Ok'
        404:
          description: 'Not Ok'
          content: {}
        500:
          description: 'Failure'
          content: { }
```

After compiling the definition using Maven, it looks like this:

```java
public interface EndpointApiDelegate {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    /**
     * GET /endpoint : short summary
     *
     * @param timestamp Given timestamp (optional)
     * @return Ok (status code 200)
     *         or Not ok (status code 404)
     *         or Interner Fehler (status code 500)
     * @see EndpointApi#endpointFunction
     */
    default ResponseEntity<Void> endpointFunction(OffsetDateTime timestamp) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }

}
```

Now, trying to send data directly via ..

- a browser's URL
- a http-file (.http)
- postman and others

```
### Sample FAILING call in .http-file
GET http://localhost:{{port}}/endpoint?timestamp=22023-01-05T13:11:40.020747+01:00
```

.. using the given example (*2023-01-05T13:11:40.020747+01:00*), **it fails**.

```
"Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.LocalDateTime]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value ... .. .
```

### Reasoning

Query parameters are parsed with a different charset (not sure these are the right words, but it fits the behaviour)
Therefore the parsing fails reading the '+'-character.

#### Resolution

```
### Sample WORKING call in .http-file
GET http://localhost:{{port}}/endpoint?timestamp=2023-01-03T11%3A29%3A47.526612%2B01%3A00
```

## Attention

In case the solution hopefully *feels impractical* ... .. .

. .. ... if it does: **YOU ARE RIGHT !!!**

### Passing Date-Time (in this case) is a 'bad endpoint design'-decision

Swagger OpenApi offers checks for **int** (minimum and maximum) and **string** (regex-pattern) directly in the OpenApi definition.

**Still** Date-Time offers special pitfalls as min/max values may be dependent on relative 'everyday passing time'.
I imagine automated min/max values are therefore *not yet implemented*.

### Is there a better solution? Sure!   :)

Use a POST request instead and define **APPLICATION JSON** in the RequestBody instead of an URL-RequestParameter.

```
components:
  schemas:
    TimestampEntity:
      type: object
      properties:
        timestamp:
          description: 'timestamp'
          type: string
          format: date-time
          example: "2023-01-05T13:11:40.020747+01:00"
paths:
  /endpoint:
    post:
      summary: short summary
      operationId: endpointFunction
      # parameters:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/TimestampEntity'
      responses:
        200:
          description: 'Ok'
        404:
          description: 'Not Ok'
          content: {}
        500:
          description: 'Failure'
          content: { }
```

That compiles to:

```java
    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    /**
     * POST /endpoint : short summary
     *
     * @param timestampEntity
 (optional)
     * @return Ok (status code 200)
     *         or Not Ok (status code 404)
     *         or Failure (status code 500)
     * @see EndpointApi#endpointFunction
     */
    default ResponseEntity<Void> endpointFunction(TimestampEntity timestampEntity) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

Using a generated Timestamp.class:

```java
public class TimestampEntity   {
  @JsonProperty("timestamp")
  private OffsetDateTime timestamp;

  public TimestampEntity timestamp(OffsetDateTime timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    return this;
  }

... .. .
```

Now the value (*2023-01-05T13:11:40.020747+01:00*) will be parsed appropriately.

**This is the end of being entangled in an URL charset-scuffle   ;-)**

Answer (score 0):

In my case

`@Configuration

**//@EnableWebMvc - if uncomment this then LocalDateTime will be as arrays**

public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
...
}`