# How can I get Spring MVC to read a path parameter with a date in "2019-3-29" format?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localdate

I want to get a date passed as a query parameter to a Spring MVC controller.

I've got this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/userProducts/2?date=2019-3-29
```

My controller class looks like:

```java
package trainingapp.userproduct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import trainingapp.calculations.NutrientsCalculationFacade;
import trainingapp.historysystemofmeals.HistorySystemService;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UserProductController {

    private final NutrientsCalculationFacade userProductCalculationFacade;
    private final UserProductFindOperationService userProductFindOperationService;
    private final HistorySystemService historySystemService;

    @Autowired
    public UserProductController(NutrientsCalculationFacade userProductCalculationFacade, UserProductFindOperationService userProductFindOperationService, HistorySystemService historySystemService) {
        this.userProductCalculationFacade = userProductCalculationFacade;
        this.userProductFindOperationService = userProductFindOperationService;
        this.historySystemService = historySystemService;
    }

    //yyyy-MM-dd
    @GetMapping("/userProducts/{userID}")
    public String getAllEatenSummedNutrientsByGivenIDInParticularDay(@PathVariable int userID,
                                                                     @RequestParam("date")
                                                                     @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate date) {
        return historySystemService.getAllEatenSummedNutrientsByGivenIDInParticularDay(userID, date);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-29T15:22:44.640+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDate] for value '2019-3-29'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2019-3-29]",
    "path": "/userProducts/2"
}
```

What should I change or add? I was trying to resolve this problem with [How to use LocalDateTime RequestParam in Spring? I get "Failed to convert String to LocalDateTime"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274353), but it didnt work.

Comment: Try to put the month on two digits, i.e `2019-03-29` .

Answer (score 7):

`2019-3-29` is a *bad input* and the `400` status code is accurate. See the [`DateTimeFormat.ISO#DATE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#DATE) documentation:

> The most common ISO Date Format `yyyy-MM-dd`, e.g. "2000-10-31".

So, to match the above format, your input should be `2019-03-29` instead.