# @DateTimeFormat variable from REST gives null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have seen [How to use LocalDateTime RequestParam in Spring? I get "Failed to convert String to LocalDateTime"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274353/how-to-use-localdatetime-requestparam-in-spring-i-get-failed-to-convert-string/40276418) but I am still having problems.

So writing a Spring Boot app which has a rest api.

The controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/climates/locationdates/{location}/{sdate}/{edate}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<Object> getClimate(@PathVariable("location") long location,
                                             @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime sdate, 
                                             @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime edate) {
      System.out.println("CONTROLLER location is " + location + " start is " + sdate + " end is " + edate);           
      return new ResponseEntity<>(climateService.getClimatesByLocationAndDates(location, sdate, edate), HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

When I use curl (using the same date format as I use for creating records)

> curl -k -w "\n" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
>   https://mint191:8453/api/v1/climates/locationdates/1/2019-12-17T11:30:00/2019-12-17T11:55:00

I get a response of

> {"timestamp":"2019-12-19T11:05:21.707+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal
>   Server Error","message":"Value must not be null!; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must not be
>   null!","path":"/api/v1/climates/locationdates/1/2019-12-17T11:30:00/2019-12-17T11:55:00"}

And in the log

> CONTROLLER location is 1 start is null end is null
>
> Request and Response is completed
>
> 2019-12-19 11:05:21.668 ERROR 21113 --- [nio-8453-exec-3]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Value must
>   not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Value must not be null!] with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must not be null!   at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]

The model is

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "climate_gen")
private long id;

private float temperature;
private float humidity;
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime date;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "location_id", nullable = false)
private Location location;
```

So the date string 2019-12-17T11:55:00 is not being converted to a LocalDatTime object. What am I doing wrong?

PS. Have used different patterns just to see if one worked.

Comment: I doubt the problem is your DateTimeFormat, it's more likely your parameter is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add @PathVariable to both sdate and edate to access value from url like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/climates/locationdates/{location}/{sdate}/{edate}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getClimate(@PathVariable("location") long location,
            @PathVariable("sdate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime sdate,
            @PathVariable("edate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime edate) {

         System.out.println("CONTROLLER location is " + location + " start is " + sdate + " end is " + edate);           
         return new ResponseEntity<>(climateService.getClimatesByLocationAndDates(location, sdate, edate), HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

Comment: I obviously misunderstood the stackoverflow entry I referenced. Many thanks @Nitika.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest several workarounds.

1. Don't just pass LocalDateTime Variable but wrap it in some class (along with other params) and in your wrapper class annotate it as:

   @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
2. Pass it as String and parse it using DateTimeFormatter on the server-side

Answer (score 0):

Missing is:

```
@PathVariable("sdate")
@PathVariable("edate")
```

hence they stay null. ;)

*Tip: if it does not work, start with a simplified prototype; ideally a unit test.
Then one can consecutively add/remove an element, like the formatter annotation, using LocalDateTime and such.*

Also the ISO format seems to be the standard format (not sure about ms), and ZonedDateTime might be more user friendly.