# Failed to convert value of 'java.lang.string' to 'java.localtime' from jsp in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, jsp, date-format

I am very new to `SpringBoot`. I have some issues converting String value which I get from jsp form to LocalTime.
For example I have jsp form where I write my input:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <form:input path="shiftStart" type="time" name="shiftStart" id="shift-start-time" min="08:00:00" max="17:45:00" step="900"></form:input>
</div>
```

and I have the following controller where I try to convert this String value to LocalTime variable:

```
@PostMapping("/add-shift")
public String createShiftForm(@ModelAttribute("shiftForm") @Valid TimeTable timeTable, BindingResult result, Model model, @RequestParam("shiftStart") String shiftStart ){
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "/add-shift";
    }
   LocalTime startShift = LocalTime.parse(shiftStart);
   model.addAttribute("shiftStart",startShift);
   return "redirect:/admin";
}
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.time.LocalTime for property shiftEnd; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.time.LocalTime] for value 09:15; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [09:15]
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: What is the format of the String you're sending ?

Comment: i am sending HH:mm,fo example 09:15 and than trying to convert it to LocalTime

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: just need to pass parametr without `@RequestParametr` in `Controller` and convert string to localtime in local variable like this:

```
 @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME) LocalTime  shiftStart
```

Here it was discussed:[How to use LocalDateTime RequestParam in Spring? I get "Failed to convert String to LocalDateTime"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274353/how-to-use-localdatetime-requestparam-in-spring-i-get-failed-to-convert-string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the `String` value to `LocalTime` to do so you need to figure out in which format you're receiving it and you just add this code :

```
LocalTime startShift = LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Elarbi said, I also recommand using a standard formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME; 

LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse("10:15:45", formatter);
```

Or directly:

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse("10:15:45", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
```

For a list of patterns consider [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) from official Oracle doc.

Comment: that didn`t help unfortunately

Comment: glad you've found a solution; I don't like the solution you've found as if someone edits your form and sends a different format, you'll deal with an exception, you don't catch it and the users gets no information about it