# Bad Request after calling GET Request

Tags: java, spring, typescript

## What I want to do:

I want to pass on two parameters from front-end to the back-end.

### This is my code:

In TS-file:

```
activeFromActiveToQuery(req?: any): Observable<ResponseWrapper>{
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        options.params.append("active_from", req.active_from.toString());
        options.params.append("active_To", req.active_to.toString());

        return this.http.get(this.resourceActiveFromActiveToURL, options)
            .map((res: Response) => this.convertResponse(res));
    }

checkOverlappingDates (recommendedSection: RecommendedSection) {
        this.activeFromActiveToQuery({
            active_from: recommendedSection.activeFrom,
            active_to: recommendedSection.activeTo
        }).subscribe((data) => {
            var retValue;
            if(data.json == ""){
                retValue = false;
            }else{
                retValue = true;
            }
            return retValue;
```

In Java-Resource class:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<RecommendedSection>> getRecommendedSectionActiveFromAndActiveToMatching(@RequestParam("active_from") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) DateTime active_from, 
                                                                                                       @RequestParam("active_to") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) DateTime active_to){
        log.debug("REST request to get active_from and active_to: {}", active_from, active_to);
        List<RecommendedSection> entityList = recommendedSectionService.findRecommendedSectionActiveFromAndActiveToMatching(active_from, active_to);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(entityList);
    }
```

### The Problem:

I get a Bad Request which tells me the following:

> "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.DateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.DateTime] for value '[object Object]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "[object Object]""

Im sorry if this is a really simple one to solve. I simply couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

But any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked this? Looks quite similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274353/how-to-use-localdatetime-requestparam-in-spring-i-get-failed-to-convert-string

Comment: @GytisTG Yes, I used it trying to fix it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: First thing first, in your log you are passing to arguments and you have only single placeholder. It is not related to your problem but just FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ISO datetime format, please be sure your request parameter (active_from and active_to) is in ISO dateTime format : `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`
e.g. `2020-10-12T00:01:01` is a good example value. Additionally instead of Joda dateTIme I'd suggest using `LocalDateTime`

Comment: Thank you! Switched from DateTime to LocalDateTime and it worked.

Comment: I am glad for you. LocalDateTIme is new and thread-safe because it is immutable so always try to prefer to use it in new code.